# Narrowing problem with Spring MVC annotation-based controller and @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Consider this Spring MVC Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test*")
public class TestController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void doStuff(Model model){
    ...
  }

  @RequestMapping(params = "myParam")
  public void doStuff(@RequestParam("myParam") int myParam, Model model){
    ...
  }

}
```

When I put this into my browser:

```
mySite.com/test.html?myParam=1
```

I expected an AmbiguousHandlerMappingException or something, since both methods seem to match the URL.

But actually the first method got called. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This smells like a bug. If you add method=GET to the second handler, it works as expected, so that's the workaround.

I've filed a bug report on this, hopefully it'll be addressed.

http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5772

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the RC1 release.